# Onclick capture get element value React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, onclick

How can I create a function that will get the number's value when clicked on it? If I click on 3 I want to get that value.

[image]

```
import { Pagination } from 'react-bootstrap';

function App() {
  
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
      
      function incrementCount() {
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
      }

      function decrementCount() {
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)
      }

      let items = [];
      for (let number = 1; number <= 10; number++) {
        items.push(
          <Pagination.Item key={number} active={number === count + 1}>
            {number}
          </Pagination.Item>,
        );
      }

      const paginationBasic = (
          <div>
            <Pagination>
              <Pagination.Prev  onClick={decrementCount} />
              <Pagination>{items}</Pagination>
              <Pagination.Next onClick={incrementCount} />
            </Pagination>
          </div>
      );

  return (
      <div>

        <p>Hello Stack</p>


          {paginationBasic}
      
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `onItemClick` method and by using currying you can capture the value:

```
const onItemClick = page => event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log({ page })
        setCount(page)
      }
```

then add `onClick` on each item

```
for (let number = 1; number <= 10; number++) {
        items.push(
          <Pagination.Item key={number} active={number === count + 1} onClick={onItemClick(number)}>
            {number}
          </Pagination.Item>
        );
      }
```

```js
const { Pagination } = ReactBootstrap;

function App() {
  
      const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
      
      function incrementCount() {
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
      }

      function decrementCount() {
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)
      }
      
      const onItemClick = page => event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log({ page })
        setCount(page)
      }

      let items = [];
      for (let number = 1; number <= 10; number++) {
        items.push(
          <Pagination.Item key={number} active={number === count + 1} onClick={onItemClick(number)}>
            {number}
          </Pagination.Item>
        );
      }

      const paginationBasic = (
          <div>
            <Pagination>
              <Pagination.Prev  onClick={decrementCount} />
              <Pagination>{items}</Pagination>
              <Pagination.Next onClick={incrementCount} />
            </Pagination>
          </div>
      );

  return (
      <div>

        <p>Count {count}</p>


          {paginationBasic}
      
      </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is what you want achieve

```
<Pagination.Item key={number} 
   active={number === count + 1} 
   onClick={setCount.bind(null, number)}>
        {number}
</Pagination.Item>,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an `onClick` handler to the `Pagination.Item` component and enclose the current index in the callback. I suggest zero-indexing your page items, then you won't need to set/compare +/- 1.

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function incrementCount() {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  }

  function decrementCount() {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount - 1);
  }

  let items = [];
  for (let number = 0; number < 10; number++) { // <-- 0-index
    items.push(
      <Pagination.Item
        key={number}
        onClick={() => setCount(number)} // <-- enclose current number/index value
        active={number === count} // <-- compare to current count value
      >
        {number + 1} // <-- transform data to displayable value
      </Pagination.Item>
    );
  }

  const paginationBasic = (
    <div>
      <Pagination>
        <Pagination.Prev onClick={decrementCount} />
        {items}
        <Pagination.Next onClick={incrementCount} />
      </Pagination>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello Stack</p>

      {paginationBasic}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit onclick-capture-value-react]

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const pageChanged = (e) => {
   setCount(Number(e.target.text )- 1);
}


<Pagination onClick={pageChanged}>
    .......
</Pagination>
```